# getting ClassNotFoundException: freemarker.cache.TemplateLoader when building code with freemarker configuration --updated

Tags: java, spring-mvc, mule, freemarker

whenever I add

```
     <!-- freemarker config -->
      <bean id="freemarkerConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
    <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/freemarker/"/>
</bean>

<!--
View resolvers can also be configured with ResourceBundles or XML files. If you need
different view resolving based on Locale, you have to use the resource bundle resolver.
-->
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
    <property name="cache" value="true"/>
    <property name="prefix" value=""/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".ftl"/>
</bean>
```

to my applicationContext.xml

this (adding code to applicationContext) is the only code that I add and build the project. Build goes fine but upon running the project this is the error I get

```
             org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: ClassNotFoundException: freemarker.cache.TemplateLoader
                at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:196) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
                at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$2.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:62) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
                at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:129) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
                at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.init(ArtifactWrapper.java:57) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
                at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:25) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
                at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.guardedDeploy(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:310) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
                at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:330) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
                at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:155) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
                at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:256) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
                at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:78) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
                at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployPackedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:275) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
                at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:150) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
                at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:100) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
                at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:152) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
                at org.mule.module.reboot.MuleContainerWrapper.start(MuleContainerWrapper.java:52) ~[mule-module-reboot-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
                at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager$12.run(WrapperManager.java:2788) ~[wrapper-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
            Caused by: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Error creating bean with name 'freemarkerConfig' defined in URL [file:/home/mudit/mule-standalone-3.6.1-ssu/apps/newsle
        tter/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: freemarker/cache/TemplateLoader (org.mule.api.lifecycle.Initia
        lisationException) (org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException)
                at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:49) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
                at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
                at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:84) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
                at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:217) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
                at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:76) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
                at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:187) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
                ... 19 more
        Caused by: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Error creating bean with name 'freemarkerConfig' defined in URL [file:/home/mudit/mule-standalone-3.6.1-ssu/apps/newsletter/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: freemarker/cache/TemplateLoader (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)
                at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:49) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
                at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
                at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:101) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
                at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:52) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
                at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
                at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
                at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:84) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
                at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:217) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
                at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:76) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
                at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:187) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
                ... 19 more
        Caused by: org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Error creating bean with name 'freemarkerConfig' defined in URL [file:/home/mudit/mule-standalone-3.6.1-ssu/apps/newsletter/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: freemarker/cache/TemplateLoader
                at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:113) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
                at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:135) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
                at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:90) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
                at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
                at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
                at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:101) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
                at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:52) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
                at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
                at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
                at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:84) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
                at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:217) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        ....
```

Comment: If you're using Maven, Try: mvn install

Answer (score 1):

looks like you are missing freemarker in your classpath. add following to your dependencies in `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
    <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.23</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: done that. But still the same. Appreciate the answer.

Comment: and are you running your code from inside the IDE or not?

Comment: @MuditDhawan let's try using command line to run `mvn install` because IDE some time stupid and they can not download the maven dependencies

Comment: @Yevgeniy I am using netbeans

Comment: does netbeans add dependencies from pom.xml by itself or do you have to trigger some action to achieve this? because ClassNotFoundException after changes i suggested sounds like freemarker still is not in your classpath

Comment: @Yevgeniy I can see freemarker-2.3.23.jar in my dependencies folder

Comment: @Yevgeniy i see the jar in classpath too

Comment: take a look inside the jar and check if the class file we are looking for is there.